# Code signing of applescript application not working when setting custom app icon

Tags: applescript

When code signing an app written in AppleScript it is no longer possible to set a custom app icon into the package content.

Normal way of setting a custom app icon is to do `show package contents` on the app file in Finder and then replace the `applet.icns` file under `Contents/Resources` with the custom icon. Problem is that this breaks the hash key signature from the code signing. This must be because the signature is calculated on the entire package on not just on for instance the compiled binaries. When you then try to execute your app depending on the context you are likely going to receive an `code signature invalid` error and macosx will refuse to run the application.

So in order to avoid this problem you somehow need to specify the custom app icon before the app package gets build as opposed to "tampering" with the signed package.

Is anyone knows of a way to do this, do let me know.

extract from the problem report:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:
Place your icon inside the `Resources` folder using a different name, i.e. *myAppIcon.png* or *myAppIcon.icns*

Check the *info.plist* and change the string value from key *CFBundleIconFile* following:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>myAppIcon</string>
```

or

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>myAppIcon.icns</string>
```

It should work even without the file suffix. After that, create and codesign your App!

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg